# How to keep a dict sorted as new items are pushed in?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary, ordereddictionary

So I have a high score file like this:

```
Markus:5000
Mike:3000
John:2400
```

And I read it to an `OrderdDict`:

```
high_scores = OrderedDict()
with open('highscores.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        name, score = line.strip().split(':')
        high_scores[name] = int(score)
```

Now as I add new scores to the dictionary, how can I keep it sorted? The only way I thought of is to recreate the dictionary every time with something like this:

```
high_scores = sorted(high_scores.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reversed=True)
high_scores = OrderedDict(high_scores)
```

But this seems rather awful behaviour, I would much prefer if the elements were put into the correct position as I add them to the dictionary, i.e. I'd like to keep the dictionary sorted at all times.

Comment: If you want to preserve sorted order, you might want to consider an alternative data structure like a priority queue.

Comment: `sort`ing it each time probably isn't as bad as it sounds because of the way  the algorithm timsort works, also it's done in C, but `sort` a list like John suggests instead

Comment: @Chris_Rands or maybe make use of the `bisect` lib...

Comment: @JonClements Yes, that's actually better I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OrderedDict is not the best structure for a highscores list.  Try a regular list of 2-tuples, and simply `sort()` it every time you add an element.

If you really dislike the explicit sorting, you could use https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sortedcontainers to do it for you.